# Error when using do.call to merge multi-band satellite image raster bricks in RStudio

Tags: r, gis, raster, r-raster

I am attempting to merge some multi-band satellite images in R (unfortunately I can't share these due to copyright issues). They are of equal size and resolution with a slight overlap between them. When I import each image individually and merge them there is no issue:

```
library(raster)

raster1 <- brick("path/multi-band-raster1")
raster2 <- brick("path/multi-band-raster2")
raster3 <- brick("path/multi-band-raster3")
raster4 <- brick("path/multi-band-raster4")
raster5 <- brick("path/multi-band-raster5")

merged_scene <- merge(raster1, raster2, raster3, raster4, raster5)
```

However, I am aiming to make my code as flexible as possible so that I can reapply it to different sets of images. To do this I load the rasters as a list and then use the `do.call()` function so that the `merge` function takes all the arguments representing the raster bricks in the list:

```
folder <- paste0(getwd(),"/Images-folder/")
list.filenames <- list.files(folder, pattern=".tif$", full.names=FALSE)
list.data <- list()

for (i in 1:length(list.filenames)){
  list.data[[i]] <- brick(paste0(folder,list.filenames[i]))
}

names(list.data) <- list.filenames

merged_scene <- do.call(merge, list.data)
```

However, when I run this I get:

```
Error in as.data.frame(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Please let me know if you can see where I've gone wrong. Many thanks.

Comment: how many dataframes do you have in the list?. if more than2 then you are looking for `Reduce` and not `do.call`

Comment: I have 5. `Reduce` is only able to iteratively apply a binary function  to apply functions. `do.call` should be able to accept more than two arguments at once. e.g. `do.call("complex", list(imag = 1:3))`
So I don't understand why I must use `reduce`?

Comment: `Reduce` gives the following memory error:
`Error in base::rowSums(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) : 
  'Calloc' could not allocate memory (25000000 of 16 bytes)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't give `names` to your bricks.

```
require(raster)

names(rlist) <- c("foo", "bar", "baz")
merged_scene <- do.call(merge, rlist)
# Error in as.data.frame(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default

rlist <- list(raster1, raster2, raster3) # no names()
merged_scene <- do.call(merge, rlist)

merged_scene
class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 77, 101, 7777, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=merc +datum=WGS84 
data source : in memory
names       : layer.1, layer.2, layer.3 
min values  :       0,       0,       0 
max values  :     255,     255,     255
```

Data:

```
raster1 <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
raster2 <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
raster3 <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))

rlist <- list(raster1, raster2, raster3)
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, not giving names to the bricks fixed the issue. (the `-` didn't actually appear in my code and was just a typo in my question)

Comment: You're welcome.  Updated my answer to ignore the typo.

Comment: Or rather, name the first two list elements `x` and `y`. That is, `names(rlist)[1:2] <- c('x', 'y')`, so that it matches the arguments for merge.

Comment: I found that unname around the list just makes it work. ```do.call(merge, unname(rlist))```