# projection(raster) = NA but raster has a set crs

Tags: r, r-raster

So I have a list of rasters which have a set crs, resolution and extent etc.
I am aiming to merge some of them together however when i try to use the merge function i get the error: Error in as.data.frame(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default

So to investigate this further i ran projection(raster1) and R came back with NA which is confusing because when run 'raster1' it shows a crs assigned to the raster

I'm not sure how to set the projection of this list of rasters and was wondering if anyone could help?
Ive already tried things like:
`sapply(rasters, function(x) projectRaster(x, crs='+proj etc')'
'projection(raster) = '+proj...''
'crs(raster) = '+proj...''

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. try `crs(my_rast, asText=TRUE)`. but perhaps this is [named_list_members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50440883/error-when-using-do-call-to-merge-multi-band-satellite-image-raster-bricks-in-rs) pertinent? hard to say as you don't actually present code you tried. a simple trick to present code or error messages, write your message, return to the next line and put ``` return to the next line and put your code or error messages, three more ``` on a new line closes out a 'looks like code' section.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you need to name the first elements of your list

```
names(yourlist) <- c("x", "y")
```